# Sequential Touch Actions throws exception

Tags: ios, testing, junit, appium

### The problem

I'm trying to scroll on an Ionic App. I would like to scroll until an element is visible. 
To test the procedure, I've written two sequential actions.
While testing just the first one is evaluated, the second one throws an exception `Support for this gesture is not yet implemented`.
How do I scroll, like a user would do, untill an element is visible if I cannot repeat actions?

### Environment

- Appium version 1.6.4-beta
- Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: OSX Sierra
- Real device or emulator/simulator: iPad Mini

### Code To Reproduce Issue

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(this.driver);  
Thread.sleep(5000);  
action.press(150, 150).moveTo(0, 350).release().perform();  
Thread.sleep(10000);  
action.press(150, 150).moveTo(0, 350).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible, and horrible, solution that I've found is:

```
while( !element.isDisplayed() ){

    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(this.driver);  
    action.press(150, 150).moveTo(0, 350).release().perform();  
    Thread.sleep(5000);  

}
```

Hopefully someone can suggest a cleaner solution.